# Filter terminal command to text file

Tags: command-line, grep

Problem: I have `dmesg | grep ttyUSB`  command that has the following output:

```
[    7.648896] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[    7.649091] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[    7.649502] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[17406.327030] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[17406.329670] option1 ttyUSB1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
[17406.334036] option1 ttyUSB2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
[90128.405694] usb 1-4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[90128.405987] usb 1-4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[90128.406295] usb 1-4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[90132.905458] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[90132.905791] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB4
[90132.906541] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB5
[90148.661532] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB6
[90148.661828] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB7
[90148.662440] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB8
```

need to redirect this output to a text file, I am using the following command for this:

`dmesg | grep ttyUSB > test.txt`

Everything works fine, but I need only list the available ports. I wish the text file output to be like this:

```
ttyUSB0 
ttyUSB1 
ttyUSB2 
ttyUSB3
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use this command:

```
dmesg | egrep -o "ttyUSB[0-9]+" | sort -u > test.txt
```

It will match and return the ttyUSB patterns.

From `man grep`:

```
   -o, --only-matching
          Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
          with each such part on a separate output line.
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still newbie in Linux. 

The output contains some duplicate ports, it is possible to remove the duplicate entries or need to do this in my programming language?

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly. just using `sort -u`.

Comment: `-u` being the `uniq` flag, of course.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue the problem is slightly harder than being advertised. Just parsing `dmesg` for instances of `ttyUSB*` won't let you know if it's currently available. It might have just been disconnected.

The following works this out by looking at the *current* status. It does this by looking for `to ...` and `from ...` instances and only uses the ones where it was a `to ttyUSB*` at the end of the line.

```
dmesg | tac | awk '$NF~/ttyUSB[0-9]+/ && !a[$NF]++ && $(NF-1)=="to" {print $NF}'
```

To quickly explain:

- `tac` reverses the input so we're dealing with the most recent first
- `$NF ~ /ttyUSB[0-9]+/` is a regex that checks the last field is a `ttyUSB*`
- `!a[$NF]++` checks that we haven't seen this field before
- `$(NF-1) == "to"` filters on the penultimate field to make sure we're dealing with `to ...` lines.

To test this I've simply taken your output and have removed the second attach. In my example ttyUSB2 was connected, then disconnected and never reconnected. It shouldn't be available.

```
$ cat testdmesg 
[    7.648896] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[    7.649091] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[    7.649502] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[17406.327030] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[17406.329670] option1 ttyUSB1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
[17406.334036] option1 ttyUSB2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
[90128.405694] usb 1-4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[90128.405987] usb 1-4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[90132.905458] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[90132.905791] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB4
[90132.906541] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB5
[90148.661532] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB6
[90148.661828] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB7
[90148.662440] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB8

$ tac testdmesg | awk '$NF~/ttyUSB[0-9]+/ && !a[$NF]++ && $(NF-1)=="to" {print $NF}'
ttyUSB8
ttyUSB7
ttyUSB6
ttyUSB5
ttyUSB4
ttyUSB3
ttyUSB1
ttyUSB0
```

And of course you can pass that through `sort` if you want. You shouldn't need to `uniq` (or `sort -u`)  it though as awk should have handled dupes already.

Comment: I am impressed with this, was actually creating a solution in Python to test if the ports are connected or not. Thank you both for the answers.

Comment: @RenatoTavares if that's your goal, I recommend you to use udev calls like this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/12939648/792066